# Calculation of euler angles

Tags: c++, glm-math

I need help understanding the math behind this code. x component of the returned vec2 and the y component of the returned vec2. Can somebody explain to me what they represent. I only know this function determinate the position of the vector in sphere coordinates.

```
glm::vec2 calcEulerAngles(const glm::vec3& vec)
{
  glm::vec3 v = glm::normalize(vec);
  glm::vec2 result(acos(v.z), atan2(v.y, v.x));
  while (result.y < 0.0)
    result.y += TwoPi;

  return glm::vec2(glm::degrees(result.x), glm::degrees(result.y));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is calculating the [spherical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) `phi` and `theta` for a unit vector.

The first component (`phi`) will be the angle between the vector and the z-axis. The second component (`theta`) will be the angle on the xy-plane. It assumes that the vector can be expressed as follows:

```
x = cos theta sin phi
y = sin theta sin phi
z =           cos phi
```

If you solve this, you get the calculations in your function. Adding `2 Pi` to `y` just ensures that the angle is between `0` and `2 Pi`.

Comment: can you explain to me how is cos(theta) * sin(phi) = acos(z_value) and sin(theta) * sin (phi) = atan2(yvalue,xvalue)?

Comment: It is `cos(phi) = z => phi = acos(z)`. If you divide `y` and `x`, you get `y/x = sin theta / cos theta = tan(theta)`. Thus, `theta = atan(theta)`. You use `atan2` to also get angles greater than 90°.

Comment: "The fact that `cos(phi) = z` implies that `phi = acos(z)`". Just noticed a mistake: The previous comment should be `theta = atan(y/x)`.